# Android Emulator Alarm Clock Crashes

Tags: android, crash, emulation, alarm

I am using the Android Emulator to debug my application, first off it is ridiculously slow, I mean like 15mins to load slow and on top of it, my Alarm Clock application fails?

Am I the only one, or do other people experience this? Is there a fix or will I just have to go cook steaks while the emulator is booting?

EDIT: I am running it on a Vista laptop, which as fixxed describe does not work well with the alarm clock failing, but I don't think it could be my laptop, its 2GB RAM Intel Dual CPU T2390 1.87GHz, its not even a year old. Could it be that I am creating new AVD's each time I run the emulator?

Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never mentioned what environment you're running in. Is it perhaps Vista? We [had a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926955/making-android-development-less-resource-heavy#930616) recently and it seems like the combination of the emulator and Vista just doesn't want to run well for some reason.

Either way something's definitely wrong. I have a laptop with a 2GHz Core2-Duo w/ 4GB RAM (rarely use more than 1.5) running Ubuntu 9.04 (32bit) and the emulator gets to a usable state in less than 30 seconds w/ Eclipse, Firefox, etc all eating more than their share of resources.

Answer (score 2):

The very first time you launch the emulator on a new AVD, it will take a lot longer to start up, because it is creating copies of disk images and customizing them for the hardware parameters you specified.

Beyond that, you may need a faster PC. Android supplies an emulator -- you are running actual ARM opcodes in a virtualized phone. Converting and interpreting opcodes on the fly takes a fair bit of horsepower in terms of CPU and RAM, on top of any other tools you might use (e.g., Eclipse, which needs a ton of resources in its own right).

On a Pentium M 2.0 notebook with 2GB RAM and no Eclipse, in either XP or Linux, the emulator will start in maybe 90 seconds and will run tolerably well.

On a dual- or quad-core CPU with 2.5GHz or better speed, with 4GB RAM and no Eclipse, in either Vista or Linux, the emulator will start in under a minute and will run rather nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I see the Alarm clock crashing problem in on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard. 2.4 GHz , 4GB RAM.

My development environment is: Eclipse 3.4.2, Using Android 1.6 SDK

The emulator takes about 2 minutes for me to start up. I think even 2 minutes is too slow. The iPhone simulator takes only a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Are you deleting the old avds that you have created?.....If not then it will slow up your computer as i tried it with different target machines......Is it necessary to create new avds every time you are trying to run the emulator?...If not i'll suggest you to stick with an avd(or delete the old ones).Hope this helps.